# как получить доступ к переменной с js файла

Tags: javascript

проблема в том что я генерирую себе обьект в volt файле, я помещаю этот обьект в переменную list, Но мне нужно использовать её в другом файле calendar.js, как я могу получить доступ с js файла к переменной list которая находиться в файле list.volt

```
list.volt
    <script>
      var list = {...};
    </script>
<script src="calendar.js">

calendar.js
var eventList = {
    init: function() {
      console.log(list)
    }
}

$(function() {
  eventList.init();
});
```

Comment: А в calendar.js анонимная функция? У неё нет доступа к переменной list.volt так как list.volt локальный объект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calendar.js
<script src="list.volt"></script>
console.log(list);
```